# File not found iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am using the `RestKit` Framework. After code merge the project building failed with error

> `#import <FBSDKLoginKit.h>` FBSDKLoginKit.h file not found. 
>   even though file is already available.

I eliminated this error by replacing  `<FBSDKLoginKit.h>` with `<FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>`.
Then another error appeared in file named `RKObjectManager.h`from the RestKit framework.
on the line 21 `#import "RKObjectManager.h"` saying **file not found**
despite the file is already available.

Comment: Are you using Pods?
Also please Goto Build settings and set build active architecture only to "NO"
And then try to build

Comment: Goto Build settings and set build active architecture only to "NO" for Target project and event for Prods Build settings

Comment: also set other linker flags to 
$(inherited) and then do clean and build

Comment: What was the code merge, and what did it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of RestKit has fixed this bug. You should upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

This started occurring for me once I upgraded cocoapods from 0.38.2 to 0.39.0 and refreshed my entire pods dir. I reverted and it's working fine now, in case you want fight this battle another day like myself.

Comment: When I reverted the cocoapods, this what appeared 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/iOS_Developer/Documents/Projects/icoach'
ld: library not found for -lPods-AFCSVRequestOperation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)